# Loading a Model record, editing it and save it from the Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, save, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to change the status of a registered user by a user activation page with `CakePHP 2`. The activation page contains an hashed string which is located in this users table:

```
id    username    email            password                  active    key
1     bill        me@domain.com    4u2iu4hk24(hashed str)    0         2ol3p(hashed str)
```

The activation procedure works with an url like this:

```
http://url.com/users/activate/2ol3pth3i89txc2zd6tg3
```

All I do is to get the hashed key, search a registered user with this `key`, load it, **remove** the hashed key and change the `active` status to `1`.
I do this procedure in this `Controller` method:

```
public function activate ($code = false) {
    if (!empty ($code)) {
        $this->User->findByActivationKey($code); // magic find instead of $this->User->find('contidions', array('User.activation_key' => $code));
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $this->User->set(array (
                'activation_key' => '0',
                'active' => 1
            ));
            if ($this->User->save()) {
                $this->render('activation_successful');
            } else {
                // here is always where I get with this code
                $this->render('activation_fail');
            }
        } else {
            $this->render('activation_fail');
        }
    }
}
```

Everything go fine but the `$this->User->save()` won't work.

Using the `debug($this->User->invalidFields());` will return this error:

```
app/Controller/UsersController.php (line 64)
Array
(
[password] => Array
    (
        [0] => Password must contain <span5</span> chars min and <span>20</span> chars max message.
        [1] => Password must contain <span5</span> chars min and <span>20</span> chars max message.
    )

)
```

Obviously, the error is from the Model but why `password` is mentioned?

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    var $validate = array (
        'username' => array (
            'MustBeCompiled' => array (
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Error message'
            )
        ), 
        'password' => array (
            'not_empty' => array (
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Password cannot be empty message.'
            ),
            'between' => array (
                'rule' => array ('between', 5, 20),
                'message' => 'Password must contain <span5</span> chars min and <span>20</span> chars max message.'
            )
        ),
        'email' => array (
            'valid_email' => array (
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Mail invalid message.'
            ),
            'existing_email' => array (
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Mail in use message.'
            )
        )
    );

    function beforeSave ($options = array()) {
        // the way to hash the password
        if (!empty ($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Maybe the problem could be in `beforeSave()`?
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the id to the model and i guess you have validation rules in place so it wont save the record. debug($this->User->invalidFields()) after the save().

And all of this should be done in a model, something like User::verify($code) and throw an exception if the user/token is not found. Remember: Tiny controllers, fat models. Models are also easier to test.

Comment: It would be grat if you show me a pratical example, of something else too, because I'm not expert in MVC so I'm not sure on how to implement `User::verity($code)` in the Controller.

Comment: `debug($this->User->invalidFields())` returns an empty array, I just get `false` from `$this->User->save()` method.